# colorbox resize interferes with an other script

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm opening a youtube video inside colorbox, since I need to open it with a specific size based on viewport size I made a function that calculates colorbox overlay size and passes it on opening:

```
overlaysize = overlaySize();

$.colorbox({
    href: url,
    iframe:true, 
    opacity: 0.8, 
    transition: 'none', 
    innerWidth: overlaysize['neww'], 
    innerHeight: overlaysize['newh']
});
```

On resize i need to update dimensions:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

    if ( $('#colorbox').length ) {

        overlaysize = overlaySize();

        $.colorbox.resize({
            innerWidth: overlaysize['neww'], 
            innerHeight: overlaysize['newh']
        });

    }

});
```

But it is not working. The box doesn't get resized
inside the same page. I'm using a script that uses colorbox.
I'm not sure if it does print some code that override my colorbox script.

Can I refer to my colorbox instance somehow?

Comment: If the content inside the colorbox resize itself on window resize so just call `$.colorbox.resize()`

Comment: if I  remove the other script that use colorbox mine works correctly

Answer (score 0):

the only workaround I found is to close colorbox on resize

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

  if ( $('#colorbox').length ) {

    $.colorbox.close();

  }

});
```